# Tracking audio (level of intensity) - android/iphone

Tags: java, android, iphone, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

Is it possible to retrieve the characteristics of the audio output signal dedicated to headphones during audio playback? I don't want to record the signal per se (that is, I don't want to record the radio with a tape player to make an 80s style mixtape), but instead I only want to know the strength, in decibels, of the signal for medical research purposes.

I was thinking this could maybe be accomplished in the same manner a visualizer does?

Comment: Write your own player? Short of that this can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing an Android app, I think you're looking for the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), through which you can query the volume of the different audio streams.

Calling [`getStreamVolume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29) should get you the data you want.

Comment: Using random media player, http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/index.html, for example, how would I call getStreamVolume and graph it?

Comment: I haven't used that player I'm afraid, so i have no idea. But your question is far too broad: I recommend treating gathering the data and graphing it as two separate tasks. Pick one, do a bit of reading, have a go at it, and then come back to post more questions (very specific ones) when you get stuck.